# Explanation for look-say sequence in Clojure

Tags: clojure

How does this function work? In particular, I am having trouble understanding the function of `juxt` here.

```
(fn [s]
  (drop 1 (iterate (fn [s] 
                     (mapcat (juxt count first) 
                             (partition-by identity s))) s)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a generator for Conway's [look-and-say sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence).

This produces sequences like

```
(1)              ; there is 1 "1" here, so...
(1 1)            ; now there are 2 "1"s here, so...
(2 1)            ; now there is 1 "2" and 1 "1"
(1 2 1 1)        ; now there is 1 "1", 1 "2", and 2 "1"s, so...
(1 1 1 2 2 1)    ; now there are 3 "1"s, 2 "2"s, and 1 "1", so ...
(3 1 2 2 1 1)    ; etc.
```

The `drop 1` removes the input sequence from the sequence of sequences output, but since that also rightfully belongs to the look-and-say sequence, we might remove it.

What we have then is `(iterate look-say initial-seq)` where

```
(defn look-say [s]
  (mapcat 
    (juxt count first) 
    (partition-by identity s)))
```

All iterate does is feed the output of the function back in as input repeatedly, producing a sequence of the intermediate results.

To understand the look-say function, work from the inside out. Let's start with the next to last line of the sample output above as a good example.

```
(def s '(1 1 1 2 2 1))
```

We want to group consecutive duplicates

```
(def grouped-s (partition-by identity s))
grouped-s ;=>  ((1 1 1) (2 2) (1))
```

And then "say" the counts of each group

```
(map count grouped-s)
;=> (3 2 1)
```

But also what we are counting

```
(map first grouped-s)
;=> (1 2 1)
```

But we'd rather get count and the item at the same time

```
(map (juxt count first) grouped-s)
;=> ([3 1] [2 2] [1 1])
```

Almost there, just need to concatenate all those together

```
(apply concat (map (juxt count first) grouped-s))
;=> (3 1 2 2 1 1)
```

Which is the same as

```
(mapcat (juxt count first) grouped-s)
;=> (3 1 2 2 1 1)
```

Note you can also write this as

```
(for [g (partition-by identity s)
      f [count first]] 
  (f g))
;=> (3 1 2 2 1 1)
```

Which might be more clear or help explain the former.